# Is "as being" in these sentences necessary?

Tags: prepositions, linking-verbs

Is "as being" in these sentences necessary?

> 1. To regard the bible (as being) literally true.
> 2. To take the bible (as being) literally true.

And if they are not necessary, should one at least keep the "as" as in:

> To regard the bible as literally true.

or can one also leave that "as" out?

Comment: You need the *as*. *Being* is optional.

Comment: The example sentences are not sentences

Answer (score 1):

The statements provided are not full sentences, however the general sentiment can be seen.

> To regard the bible literally true

Does not make sense. Although using 'being' in the sentence is optional, and does not change the meaning of the sentence in any way, you must use 'as' at least.